# copy paste range in first empty column in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I want to copy the range of cells (C1:Z1000) of worksheet3 and paste them to the first empty column of worksheet1 (in row 1). The code below blocks at the last line: source.Range("C1:Z1000").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")

'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

source.Range("C1:Z1000").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)

End Sub
```

Comment: You code is illogical. You check if the LAST column of sheet3 is empty, if not, you take the NEXT column. Which of course will never exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue was the way you were obtaining the `emptyColumn` value, as others suggested. This works for me:

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")

'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
End If

source.Range("C1:Z1000").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)

End Sub
```

The way you currently have it will pull the very last column in the worksheet, which seems to thrown an error when pasting to it. The above approach will pull the very first empty column. That is, if column C is empty, the value of `emptyColumn` will be 3

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stepping through your code?

If you do, you'll notice that the following line will always set the `emptyColumns` variable to the far right column, regardless of which columns are used:

```
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
```

By adding 1 to it and pasting you try to paste to a column that does not exist. That will give you an error every time.

Instead, try the following to find the last used column. It searches from the far right column in the first row and goes left (like typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>), in order to find the last used column:

```
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Then you can add 1 to it and paste.

Comment: I think Last column is **.End(xlToRight).column**

Comment: No, it's by design. I start to the far right (`destination.Columns.Count`) and go left, so I don't get stuck on an empty column in the middle, with more used columns to the right. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xltoright).Column

source.Range("C1:Z1000").Copy Destination:= Cells(1, emptyColumn)
```

*named arguments* are followed by a colon equals **:=**

*your code for End should be:* **End(xlToRight)**

another alternative would be:

```
source.Range("C1:Z1000").Copy 
with destination
    .cells(1,emptycolumn).select
    .paste
end with
```

I hope that helps

Philip

Comment: OK Where do you get the error? Maybe try this the second option I gave below. ALSO, **is Sourece an object like a worksheet or a workbook, or a range**

Answer (score 0):

I found this post, modified it to fit my needs. Will paste transpose

```
Sub Transpose_PasteModified()

Dim source As Worksheet
Dim destination As Worksheet
Dim emptyColumn As Long

Set source = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set destination = Sheets("Sheet2")
'Data Source
source.Range("A3:C3").Copy
'Gets Empty Column
emptyColumn = destination.Cells(3, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'In order to avoid issues of first row returning 1
'in this case #3 is the row so we're checking A3
'If row changes then change A3 to correct row

If IsEmpty(destination.Range("A3")) Then
destination.Cells(3, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Else
emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
destination.Cells(3, emptyColumn).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End If

End Sub
```